# Linq many to many query with where clause

Tags: mysql, linq, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following problem:
I have some tables "clinic", "doctor", "clinicDoctor" (representing a many to many relatioship), also I have "specialty" and "doctorSpecialty" (representing a many to many relatioship).
I want to make a linq query that find all clinics that have doctors with an especific specialty.

In resume I want to find clinics by specialty id

```
var clinicLst = (from cli in clinica.Clinic
                                  .Include(x => x.ClinicDoctor) //This is a Collection
                                  .ThenInclude(x => x.IdDoctorNavigation)
                                  .ThenInclude(x => x.DoctorSpecialty) //This is a Collection
                                  .ThenInclude(x => x.IdSpecialtyNavigation)
                                  .Where(cli => (cli.State == true) 
                                  && HERE I WANT THE ESPECIALIDAD.ID == ID BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW)
                                  select cli).ToList();
```

Please any sugestion. 
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Solution: var clinicaLst = (from cli in clinica.Clinica
                                  .Where(x => (x.IdCiudadNavigation.Id == idCiudad)
                                    && (x.IdCiudadNavigation.Estado == true)
                                    && (x.ClinicaDoctor.Any(s => s.IdDoctorNavigation.DoctorEspecialidad
                                                                    .Any(de => de.IdEspecialidad == idEsp))
                                    && (x.Estado == true)))
                                  select cli).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I think you're looking for something like:

```
var clinicList = await clinica.Clinic.Where(x => x.DoctorSpecialty.Any(s => s.Id == specialtyId)).ToListAsync();
```

**UPDATE**

Hence the "your question isn't very clear". Generally, with a many-to-many, especially if you're using EF Core, you'd have set up like:

```
public class Doctor
{
    ...
    public ICollection<DoctorSpecialty> Specialties { get; set; }
}

public class Specialty
{
    ...
    public ICollection<DoctorSpecialty> Doctors { get; set; }
}

public class DoctorSpecialty
{
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public int SpecialtyId { get; set; }
}
```

Then, `Clinic` would have something like:

```
public ICollection<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
```

Assuming a set up like that, then you'd query via:

```
context.Clinics.Where(x => x.Doctors.Any(d => d.Specialties.Any(s => s.SpecialtyId == specialtyId)))
```

Comment: The problem is that Clinic doesn't have a definition of DoctorSpecialty, but I'm going to use your answer because maybe with this .Any() I have the solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So every Clinic has zero or more Doctors, and every Doctor works in zero or more Clinics. Apparently you use a framework that implements this many-to-many relation using `virtual ICollection`, like Entity Framework does.

```
class Clinic
{
    public int Id {get; set;}  // primary key
    ...                        // other properties

    // every Clinic has zero or more Doctors (many to many):
    public virtual ICollection<Doctor> Doctors {get; set;}
}
```

Similarly, there is a many to many relationship between Doctors and Specialties:

```
class Doctor
{
    public int Id {get; set;}  // primary key
    ...                        // other properties

    // every Doctor works in zero or more Clinics (many-to-many):
    public virtual ICollection<Clinic> Clinics {get; set;}

    // every Doctor has zero or more Specialties
    public virtual ICollection<Specialty> Specialties {get; set;}
}
```

For completeness the Specialty:

```
class Specialty
{
    public int Id {get; set;}  // primary key
    public string Description {get; set;}
    ...                        // other properties

    // every Specialty belongs to zero or more Doctors (many to many):
    public virtual ICollection<Doctor> Doctors {get; set;}
}
```

> I want to make a linq query that find all clinics that have doctors with an especific specialty.

```
int specialtyId = ...
var clinicsWithSpecialty = myDbContext.Clinics

    // keep only those Clinics that have at least one Doctor with the desired specialty
    .Where(clinic => clinic.Doctors
        .Where(doctor => doctor.Specialties.Select(specialty => specialty.Id == specialtyId)
        .Any())
    .Select(clinic => new
    {
        // Select the clinic properties you want:
        Id = clinic.Id,
        Name = clinic.Name,
        ...

        // Select the Doctors you want:
        Doctors = clinic.Doctorw.Where(doctor => ...)
            .Select(doctor => new
            {
                // Select the Doctor properties that you want
                Id = doctor.Id,
                ...

                Specialties = doctor.Specialties
                    .Where(specialty => ...)
                    .Select(specialty => new
                    {
                        // Select the specialties that you want
                        ...
                    })
                    .ToList(),
             })
             .ToList(),
     });
```

For efficiency reasons, don't select any properties that you don't plan to use, especially the foreign keys to your junction tables. If Clinic [10] has 300 Doctors, then every Doctor will have the same value for the foreign key to the junction table. It would be a waste to transfer this value 300 times if you are not using it.

> When fetching data, only use Include if you plan to change the fetched data. If you only need to query it, use Select.